# How to fix SOA error: Could not find reverse address for IP

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, centos6, soa-record

I have just got to administer a Linux server (CentOS 6.8), where there are a handful of websites hosted.

There sometimes (very rare) is a problem of requesting one of the sites, let's say `example.fi`. It usually works fine, but sometimes visitors are redirected to the very first website that was ever hosted on this server, let's call it `first.com`.

I ran the DNS checks on every site hosted there, and the only one that had warnings was `example.fi`. The exact warnings from pingdom dnscheck are following:

```
Could not find reverse address for xxx.xxx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa.).

PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).
```

How can this be fixed so that the visitors are always redirected to the correct site?

**EDIT**

The domain name in question is `penhouse.fi`

Comment: Based on the described behavior I would suspect misconfigured web server software rather than a DNS problem.  Disregarding this particular issue, you may want to consider having a "neutral" default site.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't tell us what domain you're having a problem with, we can only give you wild guesses.
2. DNSCheck is an old, deprecated tool and Pingdom (unless they've hacked it themselves recently) are running an old version of it. The successor to DNSCheck is [Zonemaster](https://zonemaster.se).
3. That error cannot give the symptom you describe, so you're on the wrong track.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. The question has been now updated with the domain name: penhouse.fi